# Good alternative to NetLimiter? 

Tags: software-recommendation, networking

There is a program NetLimiter for windows. While I was using Windows it was very useful for me to find out the IP address of the person who was downloading from me, or to know IP address of any person on LAN who was using DC++ with some nick. And after that I can easily know the computer name of that person using nbtstat.

I was wondering if there is any tool for Ubuntu using which I can find out the IP address of person who is downloading from me or from whom I am downloading on LAN. I am on university LAN and we are using PtokaX and DC++ for file sharing on LAN. people sometimes put some offencive stuff on open chat on DC++ using some Nick and I don't know how to trace them while I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know enough about it to give it as an answer, but maybe Wireshark can do what you need? otherwise see  http://alternativeto.net/software/wireshark/ and http://alternativeto.net/software/netlimiter/

Comment: and if you find a good alternative to netlimiter's main functionality, please feel free to answer http://superuser.com/questions/189128/something-that-logs-network-traffic-bandwidth-usage-per-process :)

Comment: Yes this question should go in superuser.com or the unix stack page.

Answer (score 2):

NetLimiter is a traffic shaping / limiting application as far as I know, but as a consequence it is able to display traffic information connected to IP addresses.

I don't see how you could connect the nickname with the IP address if not by the current volume of traffic.

If you are looking for such information you can try `iftop`. It tells you the amount of input/output traffic by connection. (It is quite a capable tool, just needs some digging into the manual.)

Alternatively there is `nethogs` that displays the amount of traffic per application.

Answer (score 2):

Well I use [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) for a more "friendly" approach but **jnettop** also works.

`sudo apt-get install nethogs`

To run it (As root) do `sudo nethogs INTERFACE`

For example: `sudo nethogs eth0`, `sudo nethogs eth1`, `sudo nethogs eth2`, Etc...

You also have **wireshark** for Wireless (NetHogs also works with wireless connection if you are for example a HotSpot)

Then you also have:

**netcat** (Superman!) - http://nc110.sourceforge.net/
**ntop** (Web Based) - http://www.ntop.org/
**jnettop** (Very cool and friendly. Terminal Based) - http://jnettop.kubs.info/wiki/
**nmap** (Supergirl!) - Other "stuff" - http://nmap.org/changelog.html

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers seem to provide a way to limit the bandwidth

I've ended up writing this: https://github.com/chozabu/LinNetLim

It works by port, not by process (yet) - and seems to work better limiting upstream data