# Bandwidth management in ubuntu?

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, 13.04, bandwidth

I am doing my project on Bandwidth control and management. So I am looking for good bandwidth management software in ubuntu. 
Anyone can suggest me a best Bandwidth management software for ubuntu, Opensource ? A bandwidth management libary would be great. 
I am using 13.04 AMD 64 Bit Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

For limiting (Bandwidth Shaping) please read [How do I limit internet bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20872/limit-internet-bandwidth/20874#20874)

For tools used to manage bandwidth see [Software to show amount of data transfer of each process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28912/software-to-show-amount-of-data-transfer-of-each-process/28923#28923)

For several tools (Similar to netlimiter in Windows) used for managing see [Good alternative to NetLimiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83352/good-alternative-to-netlimiter/83632#83632)